# ss2tf returns unexpected value in matlab RS2016a

Tags: matlab, state-space, transfer-function

I am trying to convert a state-space model to a transfer function in matlab RS2016a. I am using the function `ss2tf(A,B,C,D)` which according to the documentation does exactly what I need. As an example I am using a static gain of 2.

**Answer that matlab returns:**

```
>> ss2tf(0,0,0,2)
ans =
    2   0
```

*edit:
`[2,0]` represents the transfer function 2/0 in the s domain. A transfer function with 0 as denominator does not make much sense and in this particular case it is wrong. The correct answer is `[2,1]` which represents the transfer function 2/1 instead of 2/0.

*original:
*[2,0] represents the transfer function 2/0 in the s domain. In my opinion the answer should be [2,1] and therefore the transfer function should be 2/1 instead of 2/0.*

**expected answer:**

```
>> ss2tf(0,0,0,2)
ans =
    2   1
```

Is there an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: "In my opinion " what do you mean *in your opinion*. This is a mathematical problem, not a subjective problem. In my opinion  `ss2tf` should cook a nice pizza for dinner, but unfortunately it represents a state space into transfer function. Its a pity it doesnt do what in my opinion should do, but well, it does rigthly the thing its supposed to do

Comment: You are right, "In my opinion" is not an ideal way to say what I wanted to say. It would be great though if the function would be able to cook pizza for dinner ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ss2tf` is a function with two output arguments, call it with two output arguments:

```
[b,a]=ss2tf(0,0,0,2)
```

You are only reading the nominator and the denominator `a` is lost the way you are calling the function.

Comment: When using the function correctly the output is:
`>> [NUM,DEN]=ss2tf(0,0,0,2)
NUM = 2   0
DEN =  1   0`
This represents the tf 2*s/s which is equivalent to 2/1 and therefore correct. I am wondering though why matlab does not simplify the tf by itself...

Comment: There are some advantages having functions which return results of predictable size.